# Advantages of ember-cli over grunt / yeoman

Tags: ember-cli

My curiousity for [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) has grown after learning about it at a recent emberjs meetup.

As far as i know, ember-cli grown out of ember-starter-kit. From there, ember-starter-kit was deprecated in favor of ember-cli recently.

I've used grunt/ yeoman for over 10 months now. I've grown favor towards it because of it's plugin ecosystem.

On the otherhand, what are some advantages of using Ember-cli vs grunt & yeoman? Or are there any advantages at all?

What can ember-cli achieve that grunt / yeoman can't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some major differences with ember-cli over grunt / yeoman:

- Ember.js utilizes [broccoli.js](http://www.solitr.com/blog/2014/02/broccoli-first-release/) as it's pipeline.
- Ember.js conventions are instantly baked in.
- Tightly integrates with ember components: ember-data, handlebars, qunit testing, etc
- Allows use of ES6 transpiler to compile ember.js. This makes code future friendly.
- Ability for "rails-like" code generation of routes, controllers, etc.

Here are some advantages of grunt / yeoman over ember-cli

- Grunt provides lots of pre-existing code and functionality. It is more mature than broccoli. Some plugins can be lacking in broccoli.
- Yeoman allows the ability to create a while project as well with generators.

[Source](http://www.ember-cli.com/#overview)